# Beginner HTML CSS code doesn't show correctly on smaller resolution

Tags: html, css, resolution, responsive

I mean I wrote some code. It appears perfectly on 1920x1080 screen, but my friend said he doesn't see the top of the website (he has smaller resolution screen) unless he decrease the scale of the page from 100% (normal) to 50%.
Of course it's smaller so its not good. There is any possibility to make it correct if everyone wants to check my webpage scale my object correctly to their resolution automatically? 
Here is my code:

```css
.grey {
  background-color: rgba(30, 32, 29, 0.5);
}
.brown {
  background-color: rgba(85, 41, 0, 0.6);
}
.red {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.purple {
  background-color: rgba(152, 0, 255, 0.4);
}
.blue {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4);
}
.yellow {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3);
}

/* CSS reset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100vh; /* középre rendezés */
  display: flex; /* középre rendezés  */
  align-items: center; /* középre rendezés  */
  justify-content: center;/* középre rendezés  */
  background: url('http://www.galaxyradio.es/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Galaxy-Background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; /* teljes nagítású háttér */
  background-size: cover;/* teljes nagítású háttér */
}

#head, #headstory {
  text-align: center; /* középre rendezés szöveg*/
}

#head {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
  margin-top: -60px;
  width: 19%;
  height: 19%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: #666;
  filter: grayscale(50%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(20%);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#profile-card {
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .5);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: hsla(0, 0%, 0%,0.9) 10px 10px 80px;
}
#music-title {
  text-align: center;
  color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  font-size: 20px;
}
#contacts {
  text-align: center;
}
@media (max-height: 850px) {

  body {
    height: initial;
  }

  #profile-card {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="profile-card" class="grey">
   <div id="head" class="">
     <div id="imgsen" class="">
       <img src="http://kepkezelo.com/images/ljookd6qf43392rycg01.jpg" alt="coder">
     </div>
     <div id="headlines" class="">
     My name is
     <p> <h1>Junior Elliot</h1><p>
     My job is
     <p> <h3>Learn programming</h3>
     From
     <p> <h2><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Don't tell anyone <br>but i dont even know.</h2>
       </div>
     <div id="headstory" class="">
       "Learn from every mistake you made. Adapt and Evolve".
     </div>
     <div id="music-title" class="grey">
         <h2>my music</h2> 
     </div>
     <div id="youtubelink" class="g">
       <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kDqdM7wLVns" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div id="contacts" class="">
     You can contact me via
     <p> <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telepathy" target="_blank"> Telepathy </a>  </p>
   </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd suggest watching some tutorial videos on responsive web design and using media queries. They allow you to style your website different at different screen sizes. This question can't really be answered until you've attempted some studying on this topic yourself and are having issues with it. Team Treehouse offers a free trial and has a good website building track, including a responsive web design section: https://teamtreehouse.com/library/how-to-make-a-website

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use "media query" that will help you to learn better Web designing....learning Bootstrap is a good thing but when you are good with css then go for Bootstrap that will help you learn better design...

[Check here how media query works](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.